# Code generation from three address code to JVM bytecode

Tags: compilation, bytecode, jvm-languages

I'm working on the byte code compiler for Renjin (R for the JVM) and am experimenting with translating our intermediate three address code (TAC) representation to byte code. All the textbooks on compilers that I've consulted discuss register allocation during code generation, but I haven't been able to find any resources for code generation on stack-based virtual machines like the JVM.

Simple TAC instructions are trivial to translate into bytecode, but I get a bit lost when temporaries are involved. Does any one have any pointers to resources that describe this?

Here is a complete example:

Original R code looks like this:

```
x + sqrt(x * y)
```

TAC IR:

```
 0:  _t2 := primitive<*>(x, y)
 1:  _t3 := primitive<sqrt>(_t2)
 2:  return primitive<+>(x, _t3)
```

(ignore for a second the fact taht we can't always resolve function calls to primitives at compile time)

The resulting JVM byte code would look (roughly) something like this:

```
aload_x 
dup
aload_y
invokestatic r/primitives/Ops.multiply(Lr/lang/Vector;Lr/lang/Vector;)
invokestatic r/primitives/Ops.sqrt(Lr/lang/Vector;)
invokestatic r/primitives/Ops.plus(Lr/lang/Vector;Lr/lang/Vector;)
areturn
```

Basically, at the top of the program, I already need to be thinking that I'm going to need local variable x at the beginning of the stack by the time that i get to TAC instruction 2. I can think this through manually but I'm having trouble thinking through an algorithm to do this correctly.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transforming a 3-address representation into stack is easier than a stack one into 3-address.

Your sequence should be the following:

1. Form basic blocks
2. Perform an SSA-transform
3. Build expression trees within the basic blocks
4. Perform a register schedulling (and phi- removal simultaneously) to allocate local variables for the registers not eliminated by the previous step
5. Emit a JVM code - registers goes into variables, expression trees are trivially expanded into stack operations

Comment: Wow! Thanks this is just what I was looking for. Questions: do I need to do the SSA transform _within_ each basic block or across the whole procedure? Do you have any pointers to tutorials, textbooks or other resources?

Comment: SSA transform is aways procedure-wide: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_static_assignment You'll just need to find a dominance frontier for each basic block where you're assigning a variable (with multiple assignment locations), insert the phi nodes there and then get rid of the redundant phis (n.b.: some may have circular dependencies).

Comment: @akbertram, `LLVM` can be a useful source of inspiration here, you can safely model your intermediate representation after it. Some important design decisions from there: do not allow to assign one register to another, and do not allow to assign a constant to a register, always substitute it in place instead.

Comment: The expression tree looks alot like the original AST -- is it worth making a round-trip through a TAC-like IR or does another sort of IR make sense when the only target is the JVM?

Comment: @akbertram, if you can stuff your JVM compilation before making TAC - then yes, you do not need it, a direct stack code generation is easier. Otherwise, if you can only stack on top of the existing compiler infrastructure, you'll need to re-construct the expression trees. Funny bit is that the JIT will do it again too.

Comment: Here's a tutorial (unfortunately, using a weird language) on various compilation modes: http://bit.ly/vnHgeo

Comment: That last link has died.